# How to trigger click event on angular element via front end

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, onclick

I'm working on a website currently created in AngularJS. I do **NOT** have access to the backend where the code exists. I need to develop a script to make changes to that page using CSS, Javascript, or JQuery. One of those changes involves creating a new element. Once the user clicks on that element(mobile users will use touchstart not click) it will need to trigger a click event on an existing element on the page.

```
        $('.DatePicker').on('click touchstart touch',function(){
            //on click of element, sim click on the bau date to pop open datepicker
            console.log('datepicker clicked');
            $('input#dateMobile').trigger('touchstart');
        });
```

This is what I currently have. I can get the console log to appear but the trigger on the element will not work regardless if I use click, touch, touchstart, touchend.

That is the current html of the element i'm trying to trigger click on :

```
<input type="date" id="dateMobile" class="payment-date__input ng-valid-min ng-valid-max ng-valid-v-date ng-valid-v-date-min ng-valid-v-date-max ng-valid-v-date-format ng-dirty ng-valid-date ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" name="dateMobile" friendly-date="" validate-date-range="" 
    ng-if="isMobile.any" min="2017-02-03" max="2017-04-04" 
    ng-model="dateModelMobile" 
    ng-blur="updateDate('dateModelMobile')" 
    ng-change="updateDate('dateModelMobile')" required="" aria-required="false" aria-invalid="false">
```

Comment: what is your html view ? you should not use jquery manipulate the dom, example `<button ng-click="orderDate()">order</button>` and in scope `$scope.orderDate = function(){... }`

Comment: There is no ng-click on the element i'm trying to trigger click on. I do not know the $scope either because i have no access to that element. I have no choice but to use jquery or javascript to edit this page. There's no other way around it.

Comment: `<input type="date" id="dateMobile" class="payment-date__input ng-valid-min ng-valid-max ng-valid-v-date ng-valid-v-date-min ng-valid-v-date-max ng-valid-v-date-format ng-dirty ng-valid-date ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" name="dateMobile" friendly-date="" validate-date-range="" ng-if="isMobile.any" min="2017-02-03" max="2017-04-04" ng-model="dateModelMobile" ng-blur="updateDate('dateModelMobile')" ng-change="updateDate('dateModelMobile')" required="" aria-required="false" aria-invalid="false"> `

that is the current html of the element i'm trying to trigger click on

Comment: according to your html you already have a function called when the input is changed : `updateDate()`. you can add your code in this function in the controller

Comment: @AlainIb i do not have access to the backend functions. so i cannot add my code there.

Comment: Angular is NOT a backend framework. It is 100% front end. It is also a javascript library. So, when you say you can only use jQuery or Javascript(which Angular absolutely is), and NOT Angular, that is very confusing

Comment: if you have access to html/js you have access to angular

Comment: Ok let me explain. The website is already live. I work on the website via a tool that only lets you modify the page through css, jquery, or javascript. (maybe angular too) however, when trying to run angular functions in the console of the webpage, i'm not able to retrieve anything because it is out of scope. Essentially, how would i achieve this forced click via the console of the web browser? 

I do NOT again NOT have any direct access to the actual html or js/angular files used for the particular page i am working on.